# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Delphi VCL XE6

Tags: json, delphi, vcl

I have to send by post to a URL string of JSON text, I use a TidHTTP component for sending by post as shown in the code below, but when I hit the submit button I skip this error, I've been searching google to another people that this happens but none of the solutions have helped me in this case.

```
var
postData:String;
url:String;
contestacion:String;
datosPOst:TStringList;
lista:TMemoryStream;
begin
datosPOst:=TStringList.Create;
datosPOst.Text:='{'+#10+'"ticketCode": "asdasd",'+#10+
'"CIF": "***",'+#10+
'"storeCode": "***",'+#10+
'"saleTimeStamp": "\/Date(123456000000)\/",'+#10+
'"email": "prueba@***",'+#10+
'"userCP": "30280",'+#10+
'"products": ['+#10+
'{'+#10+
'"Amount": 1,'+#10+
'"Description": "PRUEBA ticket",'+#10+
'"Name": "Prueba ticket 2",'+#10+
'"Price": 25.25,'+#10+
'"ProductCode": "50",'+#10+
'"Tax": 21,'+#10+
'"UnitPrice": 250.00'+#10+
'}'+#10+
'],'+#10+
'"user": "****",'+#10+
'"password": "****"'+#10+
'}';
lista:=TMemoryStream.Create;
datosPOst.SaveToStream(lista);
contestacion:=conexion.Post('http://****.com/Ticket.svc/rest/InsertTicket',lista);
```

Also if there is any way to form a json from delphi also would appreciate

Thanks

Comment: @whosrdaddy it is not a duplicate, the question you linked is about putting it in a stringlist where a stream is needed. This is about the 400 bad-request and the fact that in that case idHTTP doesn't give you back the body that you need.

Comment: You are missing a comma after the user, should be `'"user": "****",'+#10+`

Comment: the problem is not the comma

Comment: You can use the [SuperObject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/) open source library to create JSON from Delphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have the solution:

```
conexion.Request.ContentType:='application/json';
```

And is working

Answer (score -2):

Error 400 is a reply you get when there are errors in your JSON.

I would advise using another component to send your POST request, a component that does give you the body text back, because that's what you need.

[Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php) has an alternative to idHTTP.

Comment: The response text you can get from the `EIdHTTPProtocolException.ErrorMessage` property. I wouldn't suggest using a different library.

Comment: You get the error respponse, not the body, those are 2 different things. I get the error-response: [no JSON object could be decoded] but it doesn't show the information that's actually usefull : {"user": ["Invalid user"]}

Comment: @PieterB can you include the full HTTP response to illustrate where the two different things are in the response?

Comment: I can confirm that `EIdHTTPProtocolException.ErrorMessage` does indeed contain the **body** of the HTTP response.  The HTTP reply text (`Bad Request`) is in `EIdHTTPProtocolException.Message`.